# function template deduction using raw pointer as argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

case A：

```
template<class T>
    class A{
    public:
        A(T*)
        {
            cout<<"T*"<<endl;
        }
        template<class Y>
        A(Y*)
        {
            cout<<"Y*"<<endl;
        }
    };
```

then calling:

```
    A<int>p1(new int);      //T*
    A<int>p2(new double);   //Y*
```

I can understand this case.

case B：

```
template<class T>
class B{
public:
    template<class Y>
    B(Y*)
    {
        cout<<"Y*"<<endl;
    }
};
```

then calling:

```
B<int>p3(new int);      //Y*
B<int>p4(new double);   //Y*
```

Question:

I can not understand  case B and figure out why `B<int>p3(new int);` call 
the `B(Y*)` ?Does anybody know why?

Comment: Which one would it call otherwise? There is only this one constructor.

Comment: What else would it call? You only have one constructor, and both template arguments (`T` and `Y`) would both be the type `double`, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Moira  I meant B<int>p3(new int);  I made a mistake.

Comment: I think their answers is still valid ...There is just one constructor, so it is the one called. It is just that the template arguments are different in B<int>p4(new double);
T is of type in whereas Y is of type double. But it does not change your display, because your code display does not depend on the difference between both types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a template constructor type deduction for type parameter `Y` does not depend on type parameter `T` which you explicitly specify with `B<int>`.

It means that in case of:

```
B<int>p3(new int)
```

`Y` is deduced as `int` from the argument of type `int*`.

Similarly, in case of:

```
B<int>p4(new double)
```

`Y` is deduced as `double` from the argument of type `double*`.

*There is no connection between the class template type parameter `T` and constructor template type parameter `Y` - their deduction is performed separately.*

Comment: @rara ok, and what?

Comment: The shared_ptr has a constructor from pointer `template <class U> explicit shared_ptr (U* p); `,two copy constructor `shared_ptr (const shared_ptr& x) noexcept;` and `template <class U> shared_ptr (const shared_ptr<U>& x) ;` ,which can be seen from [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr/). As your answer, `template <class U> shared_ptr (const shared_ptr<U>& x) ;` can handle the (T,U) and (T,T) situation, why the `shared_ptr (const shared_ptr& x) noexcept;`  is still needed and constructor from pointer only has  `template <class U> explicit shared_ptr (U* p); `